# Android show alert when read data from usb?

Tags: android, usb

I am working on usb serial port and successful to send data to usb device but want to show alert box when getting data from usb.

For Example:
    Activity A is open and one usb barcode scanner is connected with our android device so how can we know that user press barcode trigger and read barcode and barcode device send data to our android device. and at that time i want any type of notification. Because user press barcode scanner trigger any time.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you really need ? You need to know how to display and alertdialog ? Please post code.

Comment: nope i really need any type of notification like alert or toast when user press barcode trigger and read data from android device?

Comment: in short how to read data from usb when user press usb barcode trigger?

Comment: A thread which continuously tries to read from usb is not an option?

Comment: so any better option for this?